# How to remove <page> element from inherited view

Tags: python, xml, odoo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_company_inherit_form">
            <field name="name">res.company.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_company_form" />
            <field name="model">res.company</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="zip" position="replace" />
            </field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

above shows my **company_view.xml** file and i replaced **zip** field because no need of that field in my project.also i need to remove

```
<page string="Configuration"> element from my view.
```

please advice me to do that.? i refer the doc but its also mention instructions regarding to how to remove fields from inherit view only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using  tag can remove page.

For example,

```
<xpath expr="/form/notebook/page[@string='Configuration']" position="replace"/>
```

thanks Keyur @ help.Openerp forum